# Can I use WearableListView in universal Android apps?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview, wear-os

I am developing a android app running on phones, and I wish I can use a customized `RecyclerView` that resembles `WearableListView` for Android Wear. So my question is that can I use this widget in regular Android app or do I have to implement it myself? If I can't use the native widget, are there any third-party libraries for the purpose?

Comment: I think it should work as long as you include the right libraries and dependencies.

Comment: I think it should work as it extends RecyclerView!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it but I am not sure if that is what you would want since it is designed to look good on a small screen; for example, it is designed to show only three items on the screen, etc and that is probably not what you would want on a larger screen.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up man, I will only use it on a small area of the screen. But I am wondering how can I import the class in my app...

Comment: WearableListView is part of the wearable support library so simply add that to your dependencies on the phone.